# Jackrabbit repository location

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I tried creating and retrieving nodes in a jackrabbit repository using 2 ways.

1) Second hop of [this](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/first-hops.html). It's about creating, retrieving and removing content via the Java API

2) [This](http://jukkaz.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/jackrabbit-over-http/) article which describes how to interact with Jackrabbit via WebDAV.

But what I could figure out is, these 2 methods deal with 2 repositories (locations) so that I can't retrieve a data which I added by the other method. I want to access one repository using these 2 methods. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods might as well use the same repository. The difference between the two described methods are more about the way the client interacts with Jackrabbit. The first is just Java API the second one is via WebDAV/HTTP.

In the above examples requesting `http://localhost:8080/server/default/jcr:root/` via a GET request is the same as the following piece of Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Repository repository = new TransientRepository();
    Session session = repository.login(
            new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));
    try {
        Node root = session.getRootNode();
        System.out.println(root.getPath());
    } finally {
        session.logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: If both use the same repository, why can't I access a particular data by both methods?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you're doing. You should be able to get the same data by both methods. Could you perhaps elaborate some more on what you're doing and what's not working?